# How to trim off part of image in CSS?

Tags: html, css

I want to have an image that spans the whole width of the page, but is only the height of my navigation bar div at the top of the screen. This image shows what I [mean](https://imgur.com/a/uzfv6sP). I just want to cut off the bottom 90% or so of the image, so I can create a page header that looks similar to [this](https://imgur.com/a/dbLAvlN).

Every tutorial I was finding online showed how to resize the image so that it's aspect ratio is maintained. This is not what I want. I don't want to resize the entire image, I just want to hide whatever part of the image doesn't fit within the div that it is contained in, which is only 70px in height.

Comment: Perhaps re-read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/125981 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please update with actual HTML and CSS that you have tried so we may help you fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the image in a div. In css set the div's overflow to :hidden. set your height and width to whatever you want the values to fit at. Im sure you already have an idea of those values but play around till it looks nice.

When you crop the image this way you may need to move the image around within. you can do this like so:

```
margin: -0px 0px 0px -0px;
```

here is a filled out example so you can play around with it a bit adjust the values to get a hang of it:

```css
body {
  background: #6e28d9;
  padding: 0 24px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.cropped-div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#yourPFP {
  height: 500px;
  width: 500px;
  /* the above is just to enlarge your image for demonstration purposes */
  margin: -350px 0px 0px -100px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="cropped-div">
    <img id="yourPFP" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/5ab6d2cd18f7c7867ad033a1bc73c751?s=64&d=identicon&r=PG">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This does not appear to provide an answer for what was asked - even as poorly as it was asked.